# Grey outline in Internet explorer when we set height to the div inside summernote editor

Tags: html, css, summernote

I am working in a summer note editor in which i had to add 2 lines with bottom border so user can type in the 2 lines.

[image]

I have added a div with the below css

```
.line {
     line-height:10px;
     height: 10px;
     border-botom: 1px solid #007272;
}
```

In IE alone I am getting an grey outline around the div

[image]

I would like to remove the outline when user focus to type something.kindly provide some inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by removing the height and line-height and adjusting with the padding on top and bottom.

The issue was when setting the height to any element inside summer note editor that outline is coming up in IE, so removed it and adjusted with padding.

This issue is little bit strange. I was unable to fix it in the local environment initially with the above-said code and fixed it while debugging in the high environment.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "focus", I think you mean "hover". If not, please correct me.

To remove the border on hover, just add another rule using the :hover pseudo class:

```
.line:hover {
    border: none;
}
```

You may also want to make sure that all of your HTML/CSS/JS files are IE-compatible.

Hopefully this solved your problem. If not, please  me.

Comment: Then change `:hover` to `:active`!

Comment: What do you want the user to do to remove the border? Like, do you want them to hover, to click, what?

Comment: user will type on top of the line. when you click on the line user will be able to type.once you click on the div and start typing the border is coming.

Comment: Might want to add JS then. Try using an onclick event and adjusting the styles of the element. I will edit post tomorrow to clarify.

Comment: Did it work? Is it the solution? I'm interested myself it see if it fixed your problem.